# libpng ndk-build internal compiler error in debug mode

Tags: debugging, android-ndk, libpng

I use ndk-build to compile libpng source code in debug mode, then it shows “internal compiler error” in pngrtran.c. But when I compile in release mode, it can success. Is this a bug in libpng? How I can resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug in libpng; anything a program describes as an "internal error" is a bug in the program (libpng does this, but then it shows "libpng: internal error"!)  So it's a bug in the compiler.

You should report it to the ndk guys or you could go directly to the compiler vendor (probably GNU) because they would likely to be more responsive.

You can't resolve the problem - it needs a compiler fix (maybe only to output a message that doesn't claim it's an internal error, but at least that.)  You can avoid the problem by simply not compiling libpng in debug mode.  Since I assume this is for Android so you can (I believe) mix-and-match debug and now debug code (this does *NOT* work on Windows with at least one compiler!)

You can also try working out which compiler option reveals the problem; compare the options being passed to the compiler in both release and debug, then bisect the differences to see if you can narrow the issue down to one setting.

John Bowler jbowler 2 acm.org

Answer (score 0):

The android team should know about the bug. As Its a resurface of an old one:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20862